# SA1125: why enforce "int?" as opposed to "Nullable<int>" but not within "typeof()"?

Tags: c#, stylecop

[SA1125](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1125.html): UseShorthandForNullableTypes has this description (taken from StyleCop 4.7 settings editor application):

> Enforces the use of the shorthand of a nullable type rather than the `Nullable<T>` except inside a `typeof()`.

Is there a reason why it has the exception for `typeof()` statement? `typeof(int?)` compiles just as fine - is this just a preference of StyleCop authors or is there a deeper reasoning?

**Edit**: since the official documentation does not mention this exception, I tested the following code:

```
var x = new Nullable<int>();
var y = new int?();
var z = typeof(Nullable<int>);
var v = typeof(int?);
```

Result: only the first line raises the SA1125 warning.

**Edit 2**: [The work item for StyleCop asking to fix this behavior](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/7524)

Comment: Where do you find the description you are quoting? Certainly not in the link you provided and also not in the [official documentation](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1125.html)

Comment: I'd suggest a bug perhaps, or a missed requirement. ReSharper prompts me to rewrite `Nullable<int>` as `int?` even in `typeof()`.

Comment: I found the description in StyleCop settings editor tool. Now the question is if it is accurate...

Comment: The [attached link](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1125.html) in the question also asks for using shorthand rather than `Nullable<>`. Where are you getting the quoted message ?

Comment: @Knaģis: Indeed. That's interesting.

Comment: Tested the rule and the behavior is consistent with the description - the shorthand notation is not enforced within `typeof()`.

Comment: Upvote if you want it fixed: https://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/7524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that this is at most a bug, at least a missed behaviour. The code states:

```
// Check the declaration of the generic type for longhand, but allow Nullable<> which has no shorthand
if (genericType.ChildTokens.Count > 0 && Utils.TokenContainNullable(genericType.ChildTokens.First))
{
    if (genericType.Parent == null || !(genericType.Parent is TypeofExpression))
    {
```

Which looks like it is trying to support `Nullable<>` inside of `typeof(Nullable<>)`. However, the check on `TypeofExpression` inadvertently filters out *closed* generics for no apparent reason.

Look for `CheckShorthandForNullableTypes`:

http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/249eed5b15ed#Project/Src/AddIns/CSharp/Analyzers/ReadabilityRules.cs

Answer (score 3):

While I don't actually know the reason (as I'm not the developer of this rule), I suspect it is designed this way to not generate a warning for this specific usage of `typeof`:

```
typeof(Nullable<>)
```

That being said, if this is the actual official reason, they could have hardcode the exception for this particular usage instead of writing an exception for all usages of `typeof(Nullable<X>)`.

Do note that all of this are *suppositions* only.

---

EDIT
From the [source code of Stylecop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/249eed5b15ed#Project/Src/AddIns/CSharp/Analyzers/ReadabilityRules.cs):

```
// Check the declaration of the generic type for longhand, but allow Nullable<> which has no shorthand
```

So from what I understand, the basically search for longhand generic types, and handle the special case of `Nullable<>` that they allow, because **there is no shorthand available for it**. AFAIK, `Nullable<>` only makes sense in the context of `typeof()`, so I'm guessing they made the exception for this case.

Comment: The IL is also the same for the `Nullable<int>` vs `int?` as you'd expect, so I'd say this is a bug or a missed requirement, most likely because of the open generics support in `typeof()`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Why are you mentioning the generated IL? That's not the point here. Because the C# compiler replaces `int?` with `Nullable<int>` how could the generated IL be *different*? The point here is about the StyleCop rule. And what exactly do you see as a bug or missed requirement here?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Just thinking out loud that there may have been an extremely subtle difference between the two accounting for a reason that not many people know about, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Hence I'm settled on bug or forgotten change. It couldn't be different on paper, but it doesn't hurt to check. The missed requirement or bug would be that the rule isn't catering for `Nullable<T>` inside of `typeof` likely because it allows empty generics (eg, `Nullable<>`) inside of `typeof`. Sounds to me like the engine doesn't enforce this shorthand rule in this scenario.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Of course, it could also be entirely valid that `Nullable<int>` is ignored in `typeof()` for another reason. Unless someone from the development team swans on by, we likely aren't going to get an answer. I'm just saying that it appears to have been missed because we can't find a good reason for it to be *not* considered under the shorthand rule.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I'm not sure to understand your point. `X?` is replaced by `Nullable<X>` on compilation, so the generated IL cannot differ between both. And as Stylecop is about code, not compiled assembly, the generated IL doesn't matter actually.

Comment: @ken2k My point is an abstraction over the mentioning of the IL. It was an example of considering a potential angle by which the development team decided not to enforce the rule in this instance. I'm just verbalising ideas. My actual point is that it's either done deliberately or it isn't. We have two ways to answer this. 1) directly straight from the horses mouth. Or 2) indirectly by theorising on reasons why they chose to do this. I see no reasons to choose to do this so my best guess is that it's either a bug or a missed requirement. Hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Well, I see one reason: **there is no shorthand** for `Nullable<>`. And as it only makes sense in the case of a `typeof()`, I guess the Stylecop team made the choice to allow the verbose form of `Nullable` when used in a `typeof()`.

Comment: This is a good guess but unfortunately the source code has separate checks for first for `Nullable<>` and only then for `typeof()` (http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/249eed5b15ed#Project/Src/AddIns/CSharp/Analyzers/ReadabilityRules.cs) so this isn't the real reason.

Comment: @ken2k Whether that is a reason or not is debatable. It would be very straightforward to differentiate between open and closed generics. However, I believe this one reason is the driver for why it isn't enforced. This driver is either a bug in that someone didn't cater for it where they should have, or a missed requirement in that the code just happens to not cater for it but they also didn't consider it. Either way, we are ruling out reasons for why they chose not to cater for it. I don't think "because of open generics" is good enough because that's easy to catch and specific to `typeof`.

Comment: I'm bowing out of this discussion as people are missing the point I'm making, but it doesn't matter as the code is available to review.

Comment: @Knaģis I was looking into their source code too, and the code you provided makes sense actually. Please see my edit.

Comment: The source code is very explicit about the reason and conforms this answer: "`// Check the declaration of the generic type for longhand, but allow Nullable<> which has no shorthand`" (Method `CheckShorthandForNullableTypes`)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The source code says they have support for open `Nullable`, but not the reason for why it also needlessly filters out closed `Nullable` types, which do have a shorthand.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I agree they could have filtered out only the open type. Quoting my own answer: they could have hardcode the exception for this particular usage instead of writing an exception for all usages of typeof(Nullable<X>).

Comment: @ken2k Exactly, which brings us around to this likely being at most a bug and at least a behaviour that went unnoticed. For it to have been chosen to do this seems nonsensical as it doesn't seem too difficult to cater for closed types. This has got to be the most typing for a tool that I don't even use that I've ever done lol

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth yes, I'm guessing they made a shortcut to support `typeof(Nullable<>)`, but there is a buggy side-effect because of how they write the code to support this exception. I think they had hard time with SA1125: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/6687 Bug open then closed several times ;)

Comment: @ken2k Just to add to the pain, I've commented on this issue on the CodePlex link you sent :-)